# How do I get the precursor nodes of each layer in Pytorch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I can get the summary of the model from pytorch, just like keras:

```
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
resnet = models.resnet18().to(device)

summary(resnet , (3, 224, 224))
```

result like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
        Layer (type)               Output Shape         Param #
================================================================
            Conv2d-1         [-1, 64, 112, 112]           9,408
       BatchNorm2d-2         [-1, 64, 112, 112]             128
              ReLU-3         [-1, 64, 112, 112]               0
         MaxPool2d-4           [-1, 64, 56, 56]               0
            Conv2d-5           [-1, 64, 56, 56]          36,864
       BatchNorm2d-6           [-1, 64, 56, 56]             128
              ReLU-7           [-1, 64, 56, 56]               0
            Conv2d-8           [-1, 64, 56, 56]          36,864
       BatchNorm2d-9           [-1, 64, 56, 56]             128
             ReLU-10           [-1, 64, 56, 56]               0
       BasicBlock-11           [-1, 64, 56, 56]               0
           Conv2d-12           [-1, 64, 56, 56]          36,864
      BatchNorm2d-13           [-1, 64, 56, 56]             128
             ReLU-14           [-1, 64, 56, 56]               0
           Conv2d-15           [-1, 64, 56, 56]          36,864
      BatchNorm2d-16           [-1, 64, 56, 56]             128
             ReLU-17           [-1, 64, 56, 56]               0
       BasicBlock-18           [-1, 64, 56, 56]               0
           Conv2d-19          [-1, 128, 28, 28]          73,728
      BatchNorm2d-20          [-1, 128, 28, 28]             256
             ReLU-21          [-1, 128, 28, 28]               0
           Conv2d-22          [-1, 128, 28, 28]         147,456
      BatchNorm2d-23          [-1, 128, 28, 28]             256
           Conv2d-24          [-1, 128, 28, 28]           8,192
      BatchNorm2d-25          [-1, 128, 28, 28]             256
             ReLU-26          [-1, 128, 28, 28]               0
       BasicBlock-27          [-1, 128, 28, 28]               0
           Conv2d-28          [-1, 128, 28, 28]         147,456
      BatchNorm2d-29          [-1, 128, 28, 28]             256
             ReLU-30          [-1, 128, 28, 28]               0
           Conv2d-31          [-1, 128, 28, 28]         147,456
      BatchNorm2d-32          [-1, 128, 28, 28]             256
             ReLU-33          [-1, 128, 28, 28]               0
       BasicBlock-34          [-1, 128, 28, 28]               0
           Conv2d-35          [-1, 256, 14, 14]         294,912
      BatchNorm2d-36          [-1, 256, 14, 14]             512
             ReLU-37          [-1, 256, 14, 14]               0
           Conv2d-38          [-1, 256, 14, 14]         589,824
      BatchNorm2d-39          [-1, 256, 14, 14]             512
           Conv2d-40          [-1, 256, 14, 14]          32,768
      BatchNorm2d-41          [-1, 256, 14, 14]             512
             ReLU-42          [-1, 256, 14, 14]               0
       BasicBlock-43          [-1, 256, 14, 14]               0
           Conv2d-44          [-1, 256, 14, 14]         589,824
      BatchNorm2d-45          [-1, 256, 14, 14]             512
             ReLU-46          [-1, 256, 14, 14]               0
           Conv2d-47          [-1, 256, 14, 14]         589,824
      BatchNorm2d-48          [-1, 256, 14, 14]             512
             ReLU-49          [-1, 256, 14, 14]               0
       BasicBlock-50          [-1, 256, 14, 14]               0
           Conv2d-51            [-1, 512, 7, 7]       1,179,648
      BatchNorm2d-52            [-1, 512, 7, 7]           1,024
             ReLU-53            [-1, 512, 7, 7]               0
           Conv2d-54            [-1, 512, 7, 7]       2,359,296
      BatchNorm2d-55            [-1, 512, 7, 7]           1,024
           Conv2d-56            [-1, 512, 7, 7]         131,072
      BatchNorm2d-57            [-1, 512, 7, 7]           1,024
             ReLU-58            [-1, 512, 7, 7]               0
       BasicBlock-59            [-1, 512, 7, 7]               0
           Conv2d-60            [-1, 512, 7, 7]       2,359,296
      BatchNorm2d-61            [-1, 512, 7, 7]           1,024
             ReLU-62            [-1, 512, 7, 7]               0
           Conv2d-63            [-1, 512, 7, 7]       2,359,296
      BatchNorm2d-64            [-1, 512, 7, 7]           1,024
             ReLU-65            [-1, 512, 7, 7]               0
       BasicBlock-66            [-1, 512, 7, 7]               0
        AvgPool2d-67            [-1, 512, 1, 1]               0
           Linear-68                 [-1, 1000]         513,000
================================================================
```

But in keras, I am able to get the precursor nodes of each layer.

```
Model Summary:
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)             (None, 1, 15, 27)     0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_1 (Convolution2D)  (None, 8, 15, 27)     872         input_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
maxpooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 8, 7, 27)      0           convolution2d_1[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)              (None, 1512)          0           maxpooling2d_1[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                  (None, 1)             1513        flatten_1[0][0]                  
====================================================================================================
```

How do I get the precursor nodes of each layer in pytorch? I looked at OrderDict, which has no information about the precursor nodes.
How can I get information about each layer of precursor nodes in pytorch?

Comment: What are "precursor nodes"?

Comment: Some neural networks are a DAG graph. For example, ResNet, my "predecessor node" refers to the upper layer of a layer.

Comment: That’s the “Connected to” part in Keras?

Comment: Yes, I want to get the "connect to" message in pytorch, but I didn't find a good way.

Comment: I’m not sure, but isn’t the way they’re ordered gives the same information?

Comment: Pytorch only gives information about each layer, but does not give the predecessor information of each layer, keras can do it. For example, InceptionV4, its overall structure is not chained, but a directed acyclic Figure. Maybe because pytorch is a dynamic graph?

Comment: no,Pytorch does not give its topology, its layers are sequentially arranged.

Answer (score 0):

You're right - PyTorch uses dynamic computation graphs and as such has no concept of children/ancestors by itself. For instance, the `Inception3` model [is created](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/models/inception.py#L57) by declaring a bunch of submodules and then [executed](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/models/inception.py#L94) by a long hand-coded method which just uses them in some way, in some order.

This allows for arbitrary flow control to be used, in which case you would have a hard time telling which layer is the child of a given layer - it *depends* on the data input.

For some special cases however, it is possible. For instance `VGG` models [are built](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/models/vgg.py#L75) using [`nn.Sequantial`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.Sequential), which is a list of modules applied sequentially to its input. If you have a model like

```
model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(30, 40), nn.Linear(40, 20), nn.Linear(20, 30))
```

you know that the ancestor of the second `Linear` layer (`model[1]`) is `model[0]` and its child is `model[2]`.

To my untrained eye, it appears that Inception models could be largely implemented in terms of `nn.Sequantial` containers, which would give you your expected functionality. That being said, they are not (at least not in `torchvision` model zoo), so you have no way to obtain that other than manually.